# Use IsTouching() in a trigger collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code for destroying an enemy when player touches it:

[image]

It works when the collider has isTrigger set to false. I've read the documentation and I think it's because it uses the physics engine to check whether player is touching or not.

Is there an easy way to avoid this, I like the cleanliness of isTouching and I need it to have a trigger collider so it doesn't affect the player movement.

If there isn't, is there a way to use the collider I already have to check for the collision with player?

Comment: From your code I'm assuming that when the player hits the collider, the player dies?

Comment: This code gets called when the enemy is hit while the player has the invincible powerup active. That's why it should be a trigger collider.

Comment: Is there are reason this couldn't be done within OnTriggerEnter?

Comment: Before it couldn't be done because it had many colliders, but now I simplified the fireball and maybe yes. I'm gonna try, didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with OnTriggerEnter2D as jmalenfant suggested.